# multiple shell script execution using jsch

Tags: java, shell, unix, expect, jsch

I am using Jsch library to execute about 1000 different of shell scripts in few linux machines and update the status into a table.

I used jsch exec channel [ChannelExec], it was working only for the single script, if the shell script calls another script,  ChannelExec was not giving correct result.

now I am using shell channnel of jsch. it is working well to get output from any kind of shell script.

the problem is, if I execute many shell scripts at once , I am getting all result in one bulk.

there is no way to get one Shell script executed and its result received.

if i want to get individual scripts execution result, I need to login to the machine for each script execution , this is taking very long time.

can somebody post a solution, suggestion on how to go about , login into machine once and execute multiple scripts and receive each script result individually.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class JschShellExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "10.32.248.158", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect(100);

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

            OutputStream inputstream_for_the_channel = channel.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream commander = new PrintStream(inputstream_for_the_channel, true);

            channel.setOutputStream(null);
            channel.connect(100);
            //shell script
            commander.println("cd /user/home/work ; ./checkstaus.sh ; exit");
            commander.flush();

            System.out.println(channel.getExitStatus());

            InputStream outputstream_from_the_channel = channel.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputstream_from_the_channel));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean isloginStringPassed = false ;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line.trim());
            }
            System.out.println("Result ="+sb.toString());

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("completed .. ");
        } catch (JSchException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you connect to a remote machine for the first time and after executing a command you'll get a [shell command line prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) printed to the output stream. You can use it as a marker between output of different shell commands.

You may consider using an [Expect-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) third party library which simplify working with a remote services and capturing output. There a good set of options you can try:

- [Expect4J](https://github.com/cverges/expect4j)
- [ExpectJ](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/)
- [Expect-for-Java](https://github.com/ronniedong/Expect-for-Java)

However, when I was about to solve similar problem I found these libraries are rather old and hard to use in a commercial software. So I created my own and made it available for others. It it called [ExpectIt](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/expectit). The advantages of my library it are stated on the [project home page](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/expectit).

Here is an example of interacting with a public remote SSH service:

```
    JSch jSch = new JSch();
    Session session = jSch.getSession("new", "sdf.org");
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

    Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
            .withOutput(channel.getOutputStream())
            .withInputs(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getExtInputStream())
            .withEchoOutput(adapt(System.out))
    //        .withInputFilters(removeColors(), removeNonPrintable())
            .withErrorOnTimeout(true)
            .build();
    // try-with-resources is omitted for simplicity
    channel.connect();
    expect.expect(contains("[RETURN]"));
    expect.sendLine();
    String ipAddress = expect.expect(regexp("Trying (.*)\\.\\.\\.")).group(1);
    System.out.println("Captured IP: " + ipAddress);
    expect.expect(contains("login:"));
    expect.sendLine("new");
    expect.expect(contains("(Y/N)"));
    expect.send("N");
    expect.expect(regexp(": $"));
    // finally is omitted
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
    expect.close();
```

You can also take a look a at [this](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expectit-core/src/test/java/net/sf/expectit/KarafExample.java) example interacting with a Karaf shell which captures individual command output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I will try this and accept your answer.